# OpenCV Pattern orientation and ranging

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV, but I am a skilled python/C++ programmer. I have printed out a pattern (very simple 8x8 inch square. Similar to http://www.site.uottawa.ca/research/viva/projects/stereo/calibrationPattern.jpg) and want to determine how far away it is from the camera as well as it's relative orientation in 3D space.

I've done some research and figured out that I should use SIFT, but I can't seem to find any accessible tutorials.

Do any of you have any links or tutorials to help me out?

Thanks!
Joe

Answer (score -1):

Camera calibration tutorial: [Camera calibration and 3D reconstruction](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/table_of_content_calib3d/table_of_content_calib3d.html#table-of-content-calib3d)

Books with sample code (C++) and walk-through for camera calibration with OpenCV:

- [Learning OpenCV](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516130.do)
- [OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/opencv-2-computer-vision-application-programming-cookbook/book)
- [Practical OpenCV](http://www.apress.com/9781430260790)